# Open-source group polling software

Tags: open-source, educational, forms, voting

I'm looking for an open-source app akin to Kahoot! and Socrative, for group polling in the classroom. It'd be ideal if there was a service that would host this platform, but not required.

Requirements:

- Wait for all users to answer before showing the answer
- Show a graph of how many people chose what answer

No user authentification needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already found a solution, there is a Moodle plug-in called [Active Quiz](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_activequiz) that works similar to what you want:

- Teacher starts the quiz during lesson, and students can then connect to it.
- Depending on settings, teacher can review responses in real time, re-poll question, etc
- Can show graphs of answers.

You will probably have to self-host, unless you have access to a Moodle installation.